# User password doesn't work after installing (language) updates

Tags: login, password

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my computer, but after the first update (which install many other languages), my user password doesn't seems to work anymore, and I can't login to my account from root nor can I modify anything else. What could be the problem?
P.S. I am using a french keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you were using different keyboard language settings when you key in your passwords? (i.e English <-> French) 
Otherwise you could reset your password.
Here is how to do it: 
[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)